# Use of the "_type" column with polymorphic associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphism

I have a Slot model, belonging to the Configuration model as well as another model:

In db/migrate/...create_slots.rb:

```
  t.references :slottable, :polymorphic => true
```

In app/models/slot.rb:

```
  belongs_to :slottable, :polymorphic => true
```

In app/models/configuration.rb:

```
  has_many :slots, :as => :slottable
```

In rails console I get:

```
  ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > Slot.last

   => #<Slot id: 69, slottable_id: 35, slottable_type: "configuration", number: 2, usage: "1GB 667MHz DDR2 SDRAM PC2-5300 SO-DIMM", created_at: "2011-08-09 12:12:25", updated_at: "2011-08-09 12:12:25"> 

   ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > Slot.last.slottable

   NameError: wrong constant name configuration
```

The only explanation I can come up with is that I've misunderstood the use of the slottable_type column. Have I?

At present, in app/models/configuration.rb:

```
slot = Slot.find_or_create_by_slottable_id_and_slottable_type(self.id, "configuration")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The slottable_type has to be **Configuration** and not **configuration**.

Comment: Wow! I would never have found that. Seems weird to require a capital letter in the database though.

Comment: It's not weird, it's the class name and the class name is written with a capital letter.